# How to get custom domain names to work with "php_network_getaddresses"

Tags: php, networking, windows-7, dns, fsockopen

My domain is set in the windows "hosts" file and it is named like "my.site". I'm using it for development.

But this doesn't seem to work with the `fsockopen()` open function. I get "php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known".

Is it possible to make it work?

Comment: Alas, I do not have a answer to your question.  The only thing I can recommend is finding a another way to support custom domain names (I utilize .htaccess) or to set the system up on a proper server for development.

Comment: How are you using fsockopen()?

Comment: As @KlausS. pointed out, I think there's a problem with the way you are using `fsockopen` because I just did PHP's example #1 for fsockopen with a domain name resolved using `hosts` file.

Comment: Could you share the line in your hosts file that defines the domain you're trying to use?

Comment: my hosts file is in windows, but php runs in linux within a virtual machine. could that be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This completely works for me:

```
// inside hosts file:
// 10.128.0.23 test.domain.example

$socket = fsockopen('test.domain.example', 80);
fclose($socket);
```

I can ping that domain name and get a valid answer, and it runs a web server on port 80.

I read from your comment that your PHP is inside a virtual machine - then you should try if the ping does work there also, and if not: add the domain name to your hosts file as well. Virtual machines do not necessarily inherit the name resolving capabilities of their hosts.

Comment: You're right, ping doesn't work either. Do you know how could I expose the domain to the virtual machine too?

Comment: If it doesn't work out of the box, then it probably will never do. You have to edit the two hosts files identically. You have not mentioned which setup you use, and I guess it highly depends on details. Easiest way out: Just edit the files to your wishes.

Comment: Oh I'm so silly. I didn't realize ubuntu has a hosts file too. So in windows I added `192.168.56.101  my.site` and in ubuntu `127.0.0.1 my.site` and now ping seems to work